# Не могу отправить форму через ajax без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Не получается отправить запрос на файл `chat.php` без перезагрузки страницы. Подключал Ajax но результат такой же.

```html
<form action="chat.php" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <textarea type="text" name="text" id="text" placeholder="Ваш текст..." class="text1"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" style="border: 0;">
  <img class="im1" src="/default/отправить.png"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: `не могу сделать то-то?` — очень «хороший» вопрос. никто кроме вас не знает, можете вы сделать «то-то» или не можете.

Comment: А вас кто - то просил ответить если не нравится мой вопрос.

Comment: JS с аяксо покажите, потому что код самой формы абсолютно ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: Почему не можете? Как подключали Ajax? Что не заработало с ним? Почему не должна перегружаться страница? По предоставленной вами HTML разметке, браузер ведет себя так, как положено, а имнно перенаправляет вас и ваши данные на страницу, указанную в атрибуте `action` тега `form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут стандартное применение [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) для сброса поведения по умолчанию, а потом выполнять действия которые вам нужны. Конечно было бы лучше если бы вы ещё приложили скрипт, тогда бы вам помогли ещё быстрее.